# Change page orientation Subreport, Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

I need to create a report with a subreport, but the main report has vertical orientation, and I need that the subreport has horizontal orientation, the problem is when I change the page orientation in the subreport, change in the main report.

If someone know how to put diferent orientation in the main and the subreport, please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the subreport in its own section. Then, in the Section Expert for the section in which the sub report resides, set the orientation of that section to landscape.

Comment: Thanks friend. Your answer was useful

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the layout of sub-report by going to section expert of sub-report sections and changing layout there, **individually for each section**.

Placing sub-report in a separate subsection was not required in my case.

Thank you